# Setup SQL Server ODBC driver from other computer fail

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2014 Express is installed on Windows 8. I can setup both "ODBC driver 11 for SQL Server" and " SQL Server native Client 11" by 32 bit ODBC connection on the same computer.

But, I cannot setup ODBC from other computer by both drivers.

I am pretty sure the server name, server login ID and password are correct while the test result is fail.

I [followed this to setup firewall](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Knowledge%20Center%20full%20documentation-v2.1.2/GUID-CF5C89EA-0918-4002-8391-80CBEDE0BB5E).  I use WF.MSC to enable UDP port 1434. On SQL Server Configuration Manager, TCP/IP is enabled for "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS".

Error message is attached. [image]

Comment: Have you configured the instance to allow remote connections and allowed the port through the firewall?

Comment: Dan, I update my question to include firewall message.